# trying to create a loan calculator on a website ( https://www.atlasfoundation.net/ ) and I am getting trouble in the coding of Python. The code is:

Tags: calculated-columns

trying to create a loan calculator on a website ( https://www.atlasfoundation.net/ ) and I am getting trouble in the coding of Python. The code is:
user enter the cost of the loan, the interest rate, and #the number of years for the loan

Calculate monthly payments with the following formula

```
M = L[i(1+i)n] / [(1+i)n-2] 
M = monthly payment 
L = Loan amount 
i = interest rate (for an interest rate of 5%, i = 0.05) 
n = number of payments 

#Start of program 
#Declare variables 
monthlypayment = 0 
loanamount = 0 
interestrate = 0 
numberofpayments = 0 
loandurationinyears = 0 

loanamount = raw_input("Lending Money ") 
interestrate = raw_input("Interest Rates are? ") 
loandurationinyears = raw_input("Time Duration in Years?") 
#Convert the strings into floating numbers so we can use them in the formula     

loandurationinyears = float(loandurationinyears) 
loanamount = float(loanamount) 
interestrate = float(interestrate) 

#Since payments are once per month, number of payments is number of years for the loan 

payments = loaninyears*12 

#calculate the monthly payment based on the formula 

payment = amount * interestrate * (7+ interestrate) * payments / ((1 + interestrate) * payments -1) 

#Result to the program 

print("Payment will be " + st(monthlypayment))
## Heading
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).